# Generating Uniform Point Cloud with Surface Normals from Meshes

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

I need help to create some kind of way to generate very uniform (ie. grid-like) point clouds for any mesh provided. Each of these points do require surface normal data.

Here is what I've tried:

**Open 3D:**
I imported my mesh into Open3D and used the voxelization downscaling. This *almost* worked as I wanted. Unfortunately, it generates fairly undistributed clouds. Here is an example of a Z-oriented slice of the point cloud (voxelized point cloud):

[image: Z slice of generated point cloud]

This method was also fairly expensive, computationally speaking. I had to randomly sample the object thousands of times in order to even generate the point cloud, and still left with 'bald' spots in the data. Here is how I did it:

```
N = 50000
pcd = mesh.sample_points_poisson_disk(N)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(N, 3)))

downpcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
downpcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
downpcd.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane(100)
```

**Trimesh, PyVista:** These could generate very nice voxel representations, however, as far as I am aware, they do not support finding surface normals at a point.

**PyBullet:** This might seem weird being here, but I was previously using this for a control system and used its ray casting system. I simply cast rays in a sphere around the object, which worked very well for generating point clouds. However, since PyBullet is no longer being used, I would like to avoid using this hefty library.

Are there any libraries or references I should check out to solve this? I've been itching my head for a while. I think having a raycasting library would be the best case given my requirements, but there must be lighter-weight ones than pybullet.

Please note that I do require the surface normals at each specific point cloud point.

Thank you!

Comment: Let me check If I have properly understood what you are trying to achieve: given any 3D surface mesh (for instance STL or PLY format) and given a random plane for slicing this mesh, the resulting section points must be evenly distributed, right?

Comment: Yes, however the slicing plane will always be along the Z-axis. For example, assume the user inputs 10 for ‘z-density.’ Then, 10 slices along the Z axis will be generated with end points starting at the top, and ending at the bottom of the mesh. With the other 8 being distributed along the mesh evenly. A different parameter would be used for the density/spacing of the points within a slice. I hope this makes it easier to understand.